# точное позиционирование

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо поместить `Player` в координаты `Trigger`.
`Player` идет на `Trigger`, стреляет в него

```
public class shotray : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Vector3 target;
          float dist = 100f;
        void Update()  {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, dist))
        {
                        Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
            target = hit.transform.position;
             }
```

Когда входит в `Trigger`, останавливается. Нужно, чтобы он стал прямо на `Trigger`. То есть стал на его координаты.

```
public class mowerPC : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public move sp;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKey)
            sp.speed = 15;
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        sp.speed = 0;
        player.transform.position = shotray.target;
    }
```

А само движение вот:

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public int speed;
       void Update()
    {
              player.transform.position += player.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (speed > 0)
            player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("walk");
        else player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idle");
```

Comment: У вас сейчас показано столько несвязанных переменных, что глаз разбегается. откуда вы внезапно взяли `hit.transform.position;` ? или `shotray.target;`. Я предлагаю выложить полный скрипт или хотя бы часть, где показывается откуда вы всё берете. Возможно вы не так пользуетесь функциями

Comment: Есть еще один скрипт, поворачивает player при нажатии на стрелку. Но это нажатие учитывается в "(Input.anyKey)".

Comment: Еще несколько вопросов теперь. 1) вы не докопировали код или у вас и правда пропущены закрывающие скобки в некоторых случаях? 2) в классе `mowerPC ` вам среда разработки не подсвечивала места с `sp` как ошибку, например `public move sp;` вот тут должна была подчеркнуть.  3) А какие-нибудь ошибки выскакивают до запуска и во время запуска?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Поскольку игра запускалась, я не обращал внимания на сообщение:The variable player of mowerPC has not been assigned. Указал в скрипте Player, и все работает!